# Redirect from one folder to another folder on same domain using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect from https://dev.smartlayer.co/weigl/ to https://dev.smartlayer.co/weiglpro/ without changing the url. I am using this code in htaccess which is saved in weigl directory.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/weigl/(.*)$ $1/weiglpro/$2 [R,L]
```

Am I saving the htaccess file in wrong folder ? 
This code shows me result of https://dev.smartlayer.co/weigl/ which is wrong. I want to show content of https://dev.smartlayer.co/weiglpro/

Comment: What do you mean by redirect? Do you want to host contents from `weigl` or want to automatically redirect  `/weigl` to `/weiglpro`?

Comment: Sorry, By mistake i wrote redirect but my requirement is when i hit https://dev.smartlayer.co/weigl , it should show me content of https://dev.smartlayer.co/weiglpro/ without changing the url

Comment: The path RewriteRule matches against, is only the “rest” of the full URL path after the current directory. If your .htaccess is in the `weigl` directory, then `^(.*)/weigl/` won’t match anything. You want `^weigl/` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `weigl` directory, create a new `.htaccess` file and add the following code

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex ../weiglpro/index.php
```

This will host all the contents of `/weigl` from the `/weiglpro` resource.

Then clear your cache and request the URL in the browser

Comment: I have tested the functionality at http://digaver.com/1 
http://digaver.com/2 
Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thanks. It worked out. 
can we do it based on websites too ? like if use opens one website, need to show content of other website without changing url

Comment: No that's not directly possible using `.htaccess`. However, with the help of PHP, you can achieve this using `file_get_contents` function.

Comment: I read somewhere on stackoverflow that it could be possible using proxypass